# Posting from javascript to ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I have this chunk of code on the view:

```
var variable_test = 'begin';
$.ajax({
  url : "/controller/index",
  type : "post",
  data : variable_test
}).done(function(response) {
  alert('1');
})
    .fail(function (error) {
    alert('2');
});

var eia = <%= @variable.to_json.html_safe %>;
alert(eia);
```

and on controller I have this:

```
def index
   @someVariable = 'end'
   @variable = params[:variable_test]
end
```

on execution this would be the result:

dialog message with 1 (so it was supposed to have worked and posted something)

dialog message with null

and this is the server side POST request:

```
Started POST ...  
Processing by Controller#index as */*  
Parameters: {"begin"=>nil}  
...  
...  
Current user: anonymous  
...  
Completed 200 OK...
```

So what is wrong? Is it actually posting the variable `variable_test` to controller `variable` ? If yes, why does it reads it as null? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It is sending your value in the post. The problem is that `data` takes an object as value, so if you want to read the value in the server side as `params[: variable_test]` you need to make the ajax call

```
var variable_test = 'begin';
$.ajax({
  url : "/controller/index",
  type : "post",
  data : { variable_test: variable_test },
}).done(function(response) {
  alert('1');
}).fail(function (error) {
  alert('2');
});
```

On another hand, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, The index action as you have it will try to render the index.html.erb file you have under app/views/controller/, is that the same index action that is being called in the ajax request?

Sorry for not commenting, not enough reputation.

Comment: I just want to send info back to server as needed. The way you edited it is still returning null. (and don't mind about not having reputation for comment. I know that situation well.)

Comment: after updating data on server I would like to read the new value from client.

Comment: When are you getting the alert with null? When you load the page?

Comment: I just created an empty app and added some similar code. Check [this](https://github.com/nbermudezs/dummy-ajax-rails/commit/7ad0de9134ec9935b6126536ff846f799fae61f2)

Comment: If you are getting the null when you load the page that is because it is expecting the variable_test argument to be in the url, something like http://localhost:3000/?variable_test=ilikepotatoes.

Comment: Well, that would define the variable on client side with the value, yes. But I would like to update the variable on server side and then on client side get the new updated value. Let us say that I sent the new value to a variable on server side **serverVariable** and then someone else request that variable value, I would like the updated value to be passed to the new get request.

Answer (score 1):

The way this works is actually quite simple.

Your Ajax *seems* to be sending your request to your controller:

```
Started POST ...
Processing by Controller#index as */*
Parameters: {"begin"=>nil}
```

... it's your response which is not being caught...

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$.ajax({
  url : "/controller/index",
  type : "post",
  data : {serialized: "data"}, // data should be serialized
}).done(function(response) {
  alert('1');
}).fail(function (error) {
    alert('2');
});
```

This setup *should* trigger the `alert('1')` function.

---

Handling the response is where you're falling short:

**1. `ERB` doesn't work in the asset pipeline**

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var eia = <%= @variable.to_json.html_safe %>; // won't work
alert(eia); // won't work
```

This will *not* work.

What *will* is to use the returned data inside the ajax `.done` method:

```
#app/controllers/controller_controller.rb
class ControllerController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @variable = {}
      @variable.attribute = "test"
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json { render json: @variable }
      end
   end
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$.ajax({
  url : "/controller/index",
  type : "post",
  data : {serialized: "data"}, // data should be serialized
}).done(function(response) {
   json = JSON.parse(response);  
   alert(json.attribute)
}).fail(function (error) {
    alert('2');
});
```

This should return the data, allowing you to output it into the view

--

**2. Use Server-Side JS**

In addition to the fact that `ERB` won't work in the front-end, you'll have to look at how your JS is being called.

You must remember that JS is front-end; it doesn't have *any* access to your `Ruby` variables. Thus, if you're trying to access the returned data in your view, you *either* need to capture the response from the server (#1), *or* run server-side JS like this:

```
#app/controllers/controller_controller.rb
class ControllerController < ApplicationController
   def index
      respond_to do |format| 
         format.js #-> calls app/views/controller/index.js.erb
      end 
   end
end
```

This will invoke `index.js.erb` whenever you run the `index` action - allowing you use any of the data you've defined in Ruby:

```
#app/views/controller/index.js.erb
var eia = <%= @variable.to_json.html_safe %>;
alert(eia);
```

This would also have to coincide with removing the response hooks in your front-end ajax:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$.ajax({
  url : "/controller/index",
  type : "post",
  data : {serialized: "data"}, // data should be serialized
});
```

Comment: I don't get it yet. 'var something = <%= ATserverVariable %>' Isn't supposed to be processed on server side so it will return a page with that variable value when it was requested? So lets say I post something to 'serverVariable', if someone else request it again, its not supposed to get a new value? I want to update datas on server in a way that the client side can request the new value. Also, you said that **1 - var eia = <%= ATvariable.to_json.html_safe %>;** won't work, but that line of code is recovering the proper value of the variable, so why did you say it won't work?

Comment: So, what you want is a value to be persisted so future visits see that new value? You will need to start using a database for that, the variables in a controller are not persisted. Also, that line of code works because you have in a view, if you had it .js file in your assets pipeline it won't work (note that he named the file to contain that code `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. That's what Rich Peck meant.

Comment: JS = client side, Ruby = server side. I can't read Chinese, client-side can't read server-side variables. Two different things; your `@variable` is a *ruby* variable, set in the server. That memory is only available to server memory; you cannot load it into JS without "translating" it in ways such as how I've described